Why does an invariant measure define a Schwartzman cycle?
If $M$ is a manifold with a flow $\phi_X:\mathbb{R}\times M\rightarrow M$ induced by a vector field $X\in \Gamma TM$.
Any Borel measure $\mu$ defines a $1$-current $c_\mu$, i.e. an element in the dual space $(\Omega^1(M))^*$ of differential $1$-forms on $M$, by
$$c_\mu(\alpha)=\int\limits_M \alpha(X) d\mu$$
for all $\alpha\in\Omega^1(M)$.
The differential $\partial$ of a $1$-current is defined as the adjoint of $d : \Omega^0(M)\rightarrow\Omega^1(M)$, i.e. $(\partial c)(\alpha) = c(d\alpha)$.
My question is about the following fact, which I have not seen proved anywhere:

The $1$-current induced by a $\phi_X$-invariant Borel measure $\mu$ satisfies $\partial c_\mu =0$ (i.e. is a Schwartzman cycle).

Clearly, for any $f\in C^\infty(M)=\Omega^0(M)$,$$ (\partial c_\mu)(f)= c_\mu(d f) = \int\limits_M df(X)d\mu.$$
But why exactly does $\phi_X$-invariance of $\mu$ imply that this integral vanishes?
